# Making a Kaplan-Meier plot in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to convert an instance of a Kaplan Meier into an rshiny app where I can drop down the factor that I want to use.

I have included the code that allows for the plot to be generated in the single instance. access_sam2[[x]] will refer to the column that would includes the data based on which to stratify on.

```
access_sam2<-access_sam2 %>% mutate(factorHL=ifelse(access_sam2[[x]] >=(median(access_sam2[[x]], na.rm=TRUE)), "high", "low"))  #Creates the sections
access_sam2$Area_mTLS_periHL<-factor(access_sam2$Area_mTLS_periHL)
fit<-survfit(surv_object~access_sam2$Area_mTLS_periHL)
ggsurvplot(fit, data=access_sam2, pval=TRUE, ylab="PFS",  xlab="Time (months)", title="mTLS Peri", legend.labs=c("High Area","Low Area"))
```

rShiny App:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Kaplan-Meier"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Selector for variable to plot against mpg ----
      selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                  c("Distance_iTLS_intra" = "Distance_iTLS_intra",
                    "Distance_iTLS_peri" = "Distance_iTLS_peri",
                    "Distance_iTLS" = "Distance_iTLS"))

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Formatted text for caption ----
      h3(textOutput("caption")),

      # Output: Kaplan Meier ----
         plotOutput("output$KM")

    )
  )
)


# Define server logic to plot various variables against mpg ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  access_sam2rx<-reactive(access_sam2 %>% mutate(factorHL=ifelse(access_sam2[[input$variable]] >=(median(access_sam2[[input$variable]], na.rm=TRUE)), "high", "low")))
  #reactive(if (access_sam2[[x]]>=median(access_sam2[[x]])) {
  #  access_sam2$factorHL<-"high"
  #} else {
  #  access_sam2$factorHL<-"low"
  #})
  reactive(survfit(surv_object~access_sam2rx$factorHL))
  reactive(surv_fit <-{survfit(Surv(time=access_sam2rx$Progression_Free_Time) ~ access_sam2rx$factorHL , data=access_sam2rx())
  })

  output$KM <- renderPlot({  
    ggsurvplot(surv_fit(), risk.table = TRUE, data =access_sam2rx())
  })  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am getting the error :

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
  64: mutate_impl
  63: mutate.tbl_df
  60: mutate.data.frame
  58: function_list[[k]]
  56: freduce
  55: _fseq
  54: eval
  53: eval
  51: %>%
  50: server [#2]
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Comment: The shiny id `"output$KM"` is wrong, never include `output$` in the string, that's a special variable for within the `server` component. Try replacing it with `"KM"`.

Comment: I changed to  "KM" in both places, still go the same error. I thought it should be an output because it is referring to the plot generated in the output.

Comment: No. `plotOutput("KM")` in the ui component, `output$KM <- renderPlot(...)` in the server component. Or have I misunderstood? My comment was specifically about the *string* `"output$"` ... the `$` notation is for variables in R (obviously), but inside a string it means nothing to R (and therefore just clouds the ui/server namespace incorrectly). I don't even know if it would be possible to have `"$"` somewhere in the id of a component ...

Comment: I have a new error: Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive')"
  [No stack trace available]

Comment: Don't mistake that error with correctly setting `output$KM`, the two are not the same. Your error about "active reactive" is because you are trying to access the value of `input$...` outside of a reactive component, early in your server blocks. Do `access_sam2rx <- reactive({ access_sam2 %>% ...})` and use `access_sam2rx()` everywhere else in your server block. BTW: your first call to `survfit(...)` is outside of reactive components and never stored anywhere, so is it wasted?

Comment: Just updated the code. I think that I have solved the reactive problem. This is a simple question but why am I getting:" error in access_sam2: could not find function "access_sam2""

Comment: Because I believe your `access_sam2` is *data*, whereas I suggested renaming it and using `access_sam2rx()`. I recommend against re-using the `access_sam2` for both the frame and the reactive component, it is difficult to troubleshoot and unclear where things are going wrong.

Comment: I am getting this now. Warning: Error in surv_fit: argument "data" is missing, with no default

Comment: You need to go through some more shiny tutorials: you should *always* capture the return from `reactive`, period. Also, ***everywhere*** you use `access_sam2rx`, use `access_sam2rx()`. (You're using my suggested code incompletely.)

Comment: To be more clear: `access_sam2rx` *is not data*, it is (effectively) a function that will return your data. If you think of it as a function (with no args), then you should realize you must always append `()`.